# Prestashop 1.7.5 How to get the base price of a product with combinations

Tags: php, smarty, product, prestashop-1.7

I'm looking to find a smarty variable that displays the base price from a product that has combinations. Those combinations may or may not affect the base price. I was able to find the the `$combinations` variable that contains the array of combinations which contains the "impact on price" price, but for some reason in the debug window I cannot find the base/root price before the combination's impact on price.

Anyone know if this variable is being served by default, and if not, how I would be able to add it?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
$prod = new Product($id_product);
echo $prod->price;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: use getPriceStatic method.
So, in /controllers/ProductController.php 
under around lines 231 and 234

```
$productPrice = $this->product->getPrice(true, null, 6);
    $productPricet = $this->product->getPriceStatic($this->product->id, false, null, 2, null, false, false, 1, false, null, null, null, $this->specificPrice);
```

and in line ~365 assign it to array

```
 $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'priceDisplay' => $priceDisplay,
                'productPriceWithoutReduction' => $productPriceWithoutReduction,
                'customizationFields' => $customization_fields,
                'id_customization' => empty($customization_datas) ? null : $customization_datas[0]['id_customization'],
                'accessories' => $accessories,
                'product' => $product_for_template,
                'displayUnitPrice' => (!empty($this->product->unity) && $this->product->unit_price_ratio > 0.000000) ? true : false,
                'product_manufacturer' => $productManufacturer,
                'manufacturer_image_url' => $manufacturerImageUrl,
                'product_brand_url' => $productBrandUrl,
                'productPricet' => $productPricet,

            ));
```

and then in .tpl file in your theme

```
{$productPricet}
```

Edit: tested it, does not work wery well - you get exactly the same as in workaround below... - sorry.
Simple workaround is to use formatted {$productPriceWithoutReduction} in tpl file -> will display base attribute price and won't change during attribute change.